# How to stream the output of an AgentExecutor in LangChain to my final application

Tags: python, langchain

I have an instance of an [`AgentExecutor`](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/#agentexecutor) in LangChain. The whole chain is based on [LCEL](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/). Therefore, I'd assume that using the `stream` method would produce streamed output out of the box, but this is not the case.

For instance, this code

```py
for token in my_agent.stream({"input": query, "chat_history": chat_history}):
    print(token, end="", flush=True)
```

writes out 3 elements, basically the steps taken by the `AgentExecutor`. The last one is the final answer, but given completely without any stream. This is NOT what I need, I need the output of `stream` to be a generator I can yield tokes from. I have found some [spare documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/how_to/streaming_stdout_final_only) about streaming output, but it has to do with using a callback to  stream to the standard output.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Can you add the code of how you create my_agent?